# How can I parse my data from Alamofire in Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, codable

It's my first post. So far I've always found my answers myself, but today, after plenty hours of research, I'm still hitting my head against a wall...

Here is my problem, I get a JSON from a Alamofire request and I cannot parse my data as I want to.

I have this answer :

```
{"family": {"id":1, "name": "myFamily","members": [{"userId":15, "lasName": "COLINET", "firstName":"Steve","latitude":48.290762, "longitude":4.070 },{"userId":18,"lasName":"BERTHIER","firstName":"Renaud","latitude":48.290755, "longitude":4.071 }]}}
```

I want to get a list of members in which I can pickup the firstname/lastname and latitude/longitude.
I've tried so much things that I can't enumerate...

Here is the (bad) code that I have right now :

```
func getMembers(username:String, password:String){
    var members:NSDictionary = [:]
    let parameters: Parameters=[
        "action":"getPosition",
        "username":"\(username)",
        "password":"\(password)"
    ]
    Alamofire.request(login_url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON{
        response in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let data):
            guard let json = data as? [String : AnyObject] else { return }
            members = json["family"]!["members"] as! NSDictionary
            members.forEach { member in
                print(member["firstName"])
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Thank's for your help.

Comment: I'd suggest learning about force unwrapping, and why it's not the best thing to do if you can avoid it. Unless you are sure `json["family"]` will never be nil, then you should change it. And even if you are sure, to write defensive code, you should still change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`members` is an array not dictionary

```
 if let family = json["family"] as? [String:Any] {
     if let members = family["members"] as? [[String:Any]] {
         print(members)
     }
 }
```

---

it would be better using

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let family: Family
}

struct Family: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let members: [Member]
}

struct Member: Codable {
    let userID: Int
    let lasName, firstName: String
    let latitude, longitude: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userID = "userId"
        case lasName, firstName, latitude, longitude
    }
}

do {
    let tr = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self,from:jsonData)
    print(tr.family.members)
}
catch {

  print(error)
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much !!! I'm just beginning in Swift and the answer was so simple !

Comment: better also not to use **!** especially with jsons as it may crash the app if something goes wrong in server , use swift stuff **Dictionary** instead of **NSDictionary** and **Any** instead of **AnyObject**

Comment: I've already tried something like this. I agree that it's way better but it throw me an error like `Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI' (0x10e941f78) to 'NSData'`

Comment: look for Alamofire version that returns data instead of jsonResponse or use urlsession.shared.addTask